# Parcelable not saving variable

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable, parcel

I have a data class that implements `Parcelable` where all its fields are being saved to the `Parcel` except for a variable outside the constructor.

My class:

```
data class MyParcelableClass(
    val fieldA: String,
    val fieldB: Int,
    val fieldC: AnotherParcelableClass
) : Parcelable {

    // This is the one I'm having problems with
    var troublesomeVariable: TroublesomeParcelableClass? = null
        set(value) {
            field = value
            if (field != null)
                // do stuff (irrelevant to the question)
        }

    override fun writeToParcel(dest: Parcel?, flags: Int) {
        dest?.run {
            writeString(fieldA)
            writeInt(fieldB)
            writeParcelable(fieldC, flags)
            writeParcelable(troublesomeVariable, flags) 
            /*
             * At this point, troublesomeVariable is null, 
             * even though a value has already been assigned
             */
        }
    }

    override fun describeContents() = 0

    companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelableClass> {
        override fun createFromParcel(source: Parcel): MyParcelableClass {
            val fieldA = source.readString()!!
            val fieldB = source.readInt()
            val fieldC = source.readParcelable<AnotherParcelableClass>(AnotherParcelableClass::class.java.classLoader)!!
            val troublesomeVariable = source.readParcelable<TroublesomeParcelableClass>(TroublesomeParcelableClass::class.java.classLoader)!!
            /*
             * Since troublesomeVariable has been written as null to the parcel,
             * it will obviously be null here as well
             */

            return MyParcelableClass(fieldA, fieldB, fieldC).also {
                it.troublesomeVariable = troublesomeVariable
            }
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<MyParcelableClass?> = arrayOfNulls(size)
    }

}
```

As the comments in the code show, the problem is that the variable is already being written to the parcel as null, even though it already has a value assigned - I put loads of logs and breakpoints to make sure the variable wasn't null before parcelising and indeed it wasn't.

So to sum it all up I'd like to know what I need to do in order to successfully write that variable to the parcel and retrieve it afterwards like the others. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Where and how are you calling the `createFromParcel()` and `writeToParcel()` from. Can you show that code too  ?

Comment: I created a class that converts `Parcelable` to `ByteArray` and back. It's already been tested and it's working. I would be happy to show the code but I think it would be too big for this question, but basically I'm receiving a `Parcelable` converted to `ByteArray` and I'm calling `createFromParcel()` when converting back to the original class. It works perfectly with other classes, I'm just having problems with that specific one and from what I saw it only happens when it's not in the constructor like the other fields

Comment: It should work with the code you show, so far as I can tell. You use the default getter, so getting `troublesomeVariable` without setting it in between should give the same result; if it wasn't null before calling `writeToParcel` it won't be null during the call. What happens if you put the logging directly into `writeToParcel`?

Comment: What your code doesn't show which seems important: where are you setting `troublesomeVariable` initially and if you could maybe have two instances of `MyParcelableClass` where only one has it set and you are trying to write the other.

Comment: @SyedAhmedJamil and @AlexeyRomanov thanks for the tips I tried logging right in `writeToParcel` and `createFromParcel` to see what's being written and read and in both cases it's `null`. However I decided to include `troublesomeVariable` in the constructor and write a custom setter, similar to the way we do in Java. I'll explain more in the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kotlin's data classes have the same behaviour as Java's POJOs: you initialise all the fields in the constructor and have getters (and setters, depending on need).

When data classes implement `Parcelable`, only the fields included in the constructor are actually written to and read from the `Parcel` - I realised it by using the `@Parcelize` annotation instead of my manual implementation and the IDE shows a hint telling me to annotate `troublesomeVariable` with `@IgnoredOnParcel`.

So the solution was to include `troublesomeVariable` in the constructor as a `private var` and manually implement its getter and setter, just like in Java, and it worked.